# All Questions of all favourite tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, questions, tag-watching

I have been answering question that has the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag from a long time. Recently I started learning [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme) and thought to go through some incoming questions which has the [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme) tag. But then I realized I have to keep 2 tabs open if I want to see the questions of both the tags.

Isn't there a way to get all the questions of some tags together in one page. Like a page where one can find all the questions on more then one selected tag, like [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme) together in one page.

If thats a little complex, one can also have all the questions of the all the favorite tags that a user has selected.

*Is there a way to do this? If not, then doesn't this sound like something that would be useful.*

Comment: [tag-a] or [tag-b]

Comment: @user193661, didn't get you!

Comment: "@user193661, didn't get you!" What?

Comment: @user193661, did not understand by what you mean when you said *"[tag-a] or [tag-b]"*

Comment: Search for `[tag-a] or [tag-b]` to get either-or

Comment: @user193661, wow, It works.. thanx a lot.. Can you post it as an answer so that i can accept.

Comment: There's also [`intags:mine`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20), whose sole purpose - per [the docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) - is to return "only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite"

Comment: @PaulRoub, but that's returning answers also.

Comment: `or` is actually inclusive-or, not either-or. @Haris You need to look at the advanced search tips. Use `is:question`

Comment: @user193661, yup `is:question` is working

Comment: @user193661, the problem with `intags:mine is:question` is that it needs to be refreshed for new questions to get added. Whereas, normally new questions will get added as and when they are asked.

Comment: Also, `is:q` is short for `is:question`