# Auto refreshed list of all questions in my favourite tags

Tags: discussion, support

Would a page like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/favourites work to get list of all questions with my favorite tags?

I found this question [All Questions of all favourite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311801/all-questions-of-all-favourite-tags) which suggests using `intags:mine is:question` in the search but the problem with that is the list doesn't get the "2 new questions" notification, you have to keep refreshing the page to see the latest questions.

Comment: You can't get that because the websockets only connect to a tag [`<siteid>-questions-newest-tag-<tagname>`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/158100). I guess you could write a userscript to open websockets for the questions that are in your favorites and I do know websockets are not that much throttled so it could work. But there is no out-of-the-box functionality for that.